# @ = and & why need to use in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS. Could you please explain difference between these (`&`, `@` and `=`)

When isolating scope with proper example.

Comment: The documentation should be your first port of call: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

Comment: Shortcut to link in accepted answer: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/